# How do I tell if a given NaiveDateTime (plus timezone like "US/Mountain") is in the past in Elixir?

Tags: datetime, timezone, elixir

Suppose I have `ndt` of type `NaiveDateTime` and a string `tz` like `"US/Mountain"`. How can I find out if `ndt` in `tz` is in the past?

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DateTime.html#module-time-zone-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elixir doesn't include a timezone database by default, but it does support timezones if you add one. At the time of writing, the easiest way is to use [Tzdata](https://hexdocs.pm/tzdata/readme.html), but check the [`DateTime` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#module-time-zone-database) for the latest recommendations.

1. Add `{:tzdata, "~> 1.1"}` to `mix.exs`
2. Add `config :elixir, :time_zone_database, Tzdata.TimeZoneDatabase` to `config/config.exs`
3. Use [`DateTime.from_naive!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_naive!/3) to convert to a timezone-aware `DateTime`.
4. Use [`DateTime.compare/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#compare/2) to compare the date to now.

```elixir
~N[2000-01-01 10:10:10]
|> DateTime.from_naive!("US/Mountain")
|> DateTime.compare(DateTime.utc_now())
|> Kernel.==(:lt)
```

Output:

```elixir
true
```

---

Config example:

```elixir
# config/config.exs
import Config
config :elixir, :time_zone_database, Tzdata.TimeZoneDatabase
```